# rdiff-backup fails with Not allowed to remove extended attribute b'security.selinux' from path

Tags: rdiff-backup

Recently, my `rdiff-backup`  began to fail shortly after it starts.
I run this:

```
rdiff-backup -v 9 --force /path/to/my/local/dir/ user@192.168.1.2::/mnt/my_dir/
```

After a few seconds to a minute it shows the following message:

```
2023-09-05 17:57:58.450866 -0400  <SERVER-50000>  DEBUG: Not allowed to remove extended attribute b'security.selinux' from path /mnt/my_dir
```

Then it finishes as such:

```
2023-09-05 17:58:01.966733 -0400  <CLIENT-42400>  Client received (162): None
2023-09-05 17:58:01.968834 -0400  <SERVER-50000>  Server sending (174): quitting
2023-09-05 17:58:01.969013 -0400  <SERVER-50000>  * Cleaning up
2023-09-05 17:58:01.967936 -0400  <CLIENT-42400>  Client received (174): quitting
```

In the `rdiff-backup-data` directory it creates an error log file, but it's empty:

```
$ ll error_log.2023-09-05T17:57:37-04:00.data
-rw-------. 1 user user 0 Sep  5 17:58 error_log.2023-09-05T17:57:37-04:00.data
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue and how to rectify it?